# How do I get the value of a setting in appsettings.json from configuration in programs.cs Blazor app

Tags: c#, configuration, blazor, settings

Can anyone tell me how to get the value from an appsettings.json file in my program.cs file in a Blazor (core 5) App.
Basically just need to write the "var seqUrl =" correctly. I think.
Please and thank you.

In my Main method of Program.cs I have

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()                
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", true, true)
            .Build();
        var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
        var seqUrl = configuration.GetSection("SeriLog").GetSection("WriteTo").GetSection("Name:Seq").GetSection("Args").GetSection("serverUrl").Value;
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
            .WriteTo.Seq(seqUrl, 
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            controlLevelSwitch: levelSwitch)
            .CreateLogger();
```

My appsettings.json looks like this.

```
"SeriLog": {
"Using": [
  "Serilog.Sinks.File",
  "Serilog.Sinks.Seq",
  "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "system": "Warning"
  }
},
"Enrich": [ "WithMachineName", "WithEnvironmentUserName", "WithClientIp", "WithClientAgent", "WithEnvironmentName", "WithProcessId", "WithProcessName", "WithThreadId" ],

"WriteTo": [ 
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "C:\\Temp\\Logs\\JsonLog.json",
      "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
      "rollingInterval": "Day"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": {
      "serverUrl": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx" 
    }
  }     
]
```

Comment: Why do you have `.GetSection("Name:Seq")` in your command? There's no section called that, and the looks to the right are not children of "Name".

Comment: Good question... I know it's wrong, that is why I asked if someone knew how to write that line correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider restructuring the JSON in your appsettings file. The value for "WriteTo" is an array, but I would make it just an object rather than an array, then each element should be a child object. Use the "Name" variable to name them. Like this:

```
"WriteTo": { 
    "File": {
        "Args": {
        "path": "C:\\Temp\\Logs\\JsonLog.json",
        "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
        "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
    },
    "Seq": {
        "Args": {
        "serverUrl": "http://xxxxxxxxxxx" 
        }
    }     
}
```

Then you should be able to retrieve the values using the same style that you are, just with the complete path to the variable you need. For example:

`var seqUrl = configuration.GetSection("SeriLog:WriteTo:Seq:serverUrl").Value;`
I don't remember if this syntax is 100% correct or not (the path might not be colon separated, I'm not completely sure) but this concept should work. You just weren't entering the correct names into the `.GetSection()` method in your code, and I think it gets kind of tricky when you are trying to retrieve an array element like this, hence my suggestion to convert from array to a simple object.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks....